# Output difference when calling string()

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I want to concatenate a number of variables having different types into a string. This works well:

```
q)"select ", string[10:00:00] ," abc"
"select 10:00:00 abc"
```

When I call string with parenthesis the output is different:

```
q)"select ", string(10:00:00) ," abc"
"s"
"e"
"l"
"e"
"c"
"t"
" "
"10:00:00"
," "
,"a"
,"b"
,"c"
```

I think in the first example the function string is invoked with an atom parameter of type time, while in the second call a time *list* is created before invoking string.

What does the output indicate in the second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With string[10:00:00], you are calling the string function on the input 10:00:00. With string (10:00:00) ," abc" , you are acually joinng (10:00:00) to "abc" and then stringing the results. You have to remember that execution is carried out from right to left.

```
q)(10:00:00) ," abc"
10:00:00
" "
"a"
"b"
"c"
q)string (10:00:00) ," abc"
"10:00:00"
," "
,"a"
,"b"
,"c"
```

Comment: Why are the results printed vertically in both examples? What are the types produced by each command in your answer?

Comment: " abc" is just a list of 4 character elements. When you join 10:00:00 you are creating a mixed list of 5 elements. 

`q)count (10:00:00)," abc"`
(returns 5).

In order to produce 2 list of lists, you would first need to enlist the character string.

`q)count l:(10:00:00),enlist " abc"`
(returns 2).
`q)l`
(returns (10:00:00;"abc"))

Comment: ok, so the commas in the second command output indicate different invocations to string(), one for each atom type (and not a list like in the first command result). Am I correct?